# Array "subscript out of range" odd behavior

Tags: arrays, vba

Consider this code in MS Word VBA:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim x() As Document
    ReDim Preserve x(UBound(x) + 1)
    Set x(UBound(x)) = Application.ActiveDocument
End Sub
```

If I place the cursor inside and hit F5 to run it, I get an error

> subscript out of range

on `ReDim Preserve x(UBound(x) + 1)`.  Specifically, it doesn't like `UBound(x)`, although it *should* return `-1` based on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95b8f22f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (see under "return value").

Now, if I set a break point on `ReDim Preserve x(UBound(x) + 1)`, run it, and then hover the cursor over `UBound(x)`, it indicates the same thing:

[image]

But I've discovered that if I then hover over the variable `x` in the following line:

[image]

and then go back and again hover over `UBound(x)` in the line above, I get a different result:

[image]

Then, if I hit F5 to run the rest of the code, indeed, I get no error that time.

Furthermore, if I change my code to add `IsArray(x)`:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim x() As Document
    IsArray (x) 'This is just here to preclude VBA array "bug"
    ReDim Preserve x(UBound(x) + 1)
    Set x(UBound(x)) = Application.ActiveDocument
End Sub
```

It also runs fine.  What is going on, and how can I get my code to work at runtime without the `IsArray(x)` hack?

Answer (score 0):

MSDN:

> If Array has only one element, UBound returns 0. If Array has no
>   elements, for example if it is a zero-length string, UBound returns
>   -1.

It isn't that the array has no elements, it is un-initialized, or doesn't have dimensions. You shouldn't rely on the value of `UBound` without first using `ReDim` on the array at least once, or without the use of error handling.

A better approach is to use error handling:

```
Dim x() As Document

Dim n As Long
On Error Resume Next
Err.Clear
n = LBound(x)
If Err.Number = 0 Then
    Debug.Print "Array is allocated."
Else
    Debug.Print "Array is not allocated."
End If
```

See this [link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/isarrayallocated.aspx) for other considerations.

Alternatively, if possible, ensure that the array is dimensioned (`ReDim`) as least once.